# Closing of TCP-socket and tcp_fin() in linux kernel/

Tags: linux, tcp, linux-kernel

I have a trouble with [tcp_fin()](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.2.1/net/ipv4/tcp_input.c#L4139) function. It should process incoming TCP-segments with FIN flag, but when I add tracepoint or just `printk` at the begin of this function, this tracepoint handler is never calls (or no any messages from printk).

My actions:

1. Add tracepoint or `printk` to `tcp_fin()`
2. Build & boot new kernel
3. Run something like this:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash

   nflows=50

   on_int()
   {
       echo "$nflows skeeped"
       exit 0
   }

   trap 'on_int' INT

   while [ $nflows -ne 0 ]
   do
       iperf -n 5M -c X.X.X.X
       nflows=$(( $nflows - 1))
       echo "======================"
       echo $nflows
       echo "======================"
   done
   ```

And as the result I should to observe calls of `tcp_fin()`, but nothing happens.

Comment: Are you sure the connections are properly set up and torn down (i.e. they're not terminated with RST or even never properly set up )

Comment: @nos Yep, it is setted up properly and shouldn't be reseted. Iperf should close connection at the end, so we will have 50 FIN-marked segments, but no one such trace observed.

Comment: I'd verify that with wireshark though. Also, which log level did your printk use - just in case your syslog is set to not show logs of that level.

Comment: @nos Thanks! Log level is KERN_ERR, and it should be enough. Other such messages (in other functions)  syslog shows normally. If I'd find anything, I will write here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I wrote a few days ago tcp_fin() processed incoming FIN-segment, but in contrast to RFC-793 not each connection ended by two FIN-segments (A->B, B->A). So in some cases we have only outgoing FIN and no more.